# Adding multiple ID's to javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I'm a Javascript newbie, and am trying to add multiple ID's to this script that adds plus/minus symbols to my bootstrap accordions:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  var $active = $('#accordion .panel-collapse.in').prev().addClass('active');
  $active.find('a').append('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus pull-right"></span>');
  $('#accordion .panel-heading').not($active).find('a').prepend('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-right"></span>');
  $('#accordion').on('show.bs.collapse', function (e)
  {
    $('#accordion .panel-heading.active').removeClass('active').find('.glyphicon').toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus');
    $(e.target).prev().addClass('active').find('.glyphicon').toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus');
  });
  $('#accordion').on('hide.bs.collapse', function (e)
  {
    $(e.target).prev().removeClass('active').find('.glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-minus').addClass('glyphicon-plus');
  });
});
```

Right now this code only works on one accordion, and not all four that I have on the page: #accordion, #accordion2, #accordion3, #accordion4.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: 1) replace ID with something like `data-role="accordion"`, 2) replace each 'inner lookup' (like `$('#acc .panel-heading.active')`) with `$(this).find('.panel-heading.active')` etc.

Comment: Im not really sure what u are trying to do.. U wanna loop trough all id's or just wanna add same function to each id..

Comment: You could try: `$('[id*="accordion"]')` more info: [How do you select all id tags that contain a certain string in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126218/how-do-you-select-all-id-tags-that-contain-a-certain-string-in-javascript)

Comment: I think add the same function to each ID

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL Looks like your solution works! Thanks for sending over.

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

```
    $('[id*="accordion"]').click(function(){
      let active = $('#'+$(this).attr("id")+' .panel-collapse.in').prev().addClass('active');
      $active.find('a').append('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus pull-right"></span>');
      $('#'+$(this).attr("id")+' .panel-heading').not($active).find('a').prepend('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-right"></span>');
      $(this).on('show.bs.collapse', function (e)
      {
        $('#'+$(this).attr("id")+' .panel-heading.active').removeClass('active').find('.glyphicon').toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus');
        $(e.target).prev().addClass('active').find('.glyphicon').toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus');
      });
      $(this).on('hide.bs.collapse', function (e)
      {
        $(e.target).prev().removeClass('active').find('.glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-minus').addClass('glyphicon-plus');
      });
    });
```

I try to target all elements which contain "accordion" in their id and then modify your code to target the clicked "accordeon" by its ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop to iterate through each of your id's and add the number to the end of each selector, the JS would operate as follows:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
for (var i =1; i<=4; i++) {
  // Example code
  $('#accordion'+i+'').css('background','#ff0000');
}
});
```

See this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/6fk8qk6d/

Answer (score 0):

One of the engineers I work with did the following, which seems to work well:

```
jQuery(function () {
jQuery( ".accordion" ).each(function( index ) {
var i = index+1;
var jQueryactive = jQuery('#accordion'+i+' .panel-collapse.in').prev().addClass('active');
jQueryactive.find('a').append('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus pull-right"></span>');
  jQuery('#accordion'+i+' .panel-heading').not(jQueryactive).find('a').prepend('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-right"></span>');
  jQuery('#accordion'+i).on('show.bs.collapse', function (e) {
jQuery('#accordion'+i+' .panel-heading.active').removeClass('active').find('.glyphicon').toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus');
jQuery(e.target).prev().addClass('active').find('.glyphicon').toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus');
  } );
  jQuery('#accordion'+i).on('hide.bs.collapse', function (e) {
jQuery(e.target).prev().removeClass('active').find('.glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-minus').addClass('glyphicon-plus');
  } );
});
});
```

Thanks to everyone who tried to help!