# jQuery Finding a control with only a partial reference ID

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

is it possible to search for the a control on a webform, where you just want to match "anything" for part of it ie:

I have various buttons on a page - which take the id format: ID#(id1)#(id2)#(date) - for example:

```
ID-8258-3103-2011-12-18
ID-8258-3104-2011-12-18
ID-8258-3105-2011-12-18
```

I want to pass the (id1) and (date) in a querystring, and then have jQuery search for the first control on the page, which matches the (id1) and (date) and *any* (id2) - so for example, I pass 8252 and 2011-12-18 - so how would I find the first control above, from jQuery?

```
$("#ID-8252-????????-2011-12-18")
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Instead of using the `#id` selector, you can combine multiple attribute selectors, which filters the id attribute (one for the beginning of the id, one for the end):

```
$('[id^="ID-8258"][id$="2011-12-18"]').addClass('found');
```

To select only the first match, use the `:first` selector (not the same as the `:first-child` selector!)

```
$('[id^="ID-8258"][id$="2011-12-18"]:first').addClass('found');
```

See http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ for reference.

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/wbLZ8/3/

It seems that these selectors can be used even with IE7, if you want to use them in plain CSS.

Comment: It is possible for it to find the *first* control, and then stop after that?

Thanks again, Mark

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use a filter in your selector, as discussed in [jQuery selector regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions). (Check nickf's response for an example).

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be most helpful [jquery-wildcard-selectors-some-simple-examples](http://rosshawkins.net/archive/2011/10/14/jquery-wildcard-selectors-some-simple-examples.aspx)