# How to do it multiple select by id?

Tags: jquery

I have many divs in ids:

```
<div class="nameclass" id="name<?= $id; ?>">
    something
</div>
```

And I want to put css to all, but by id not class:

```
$('div.nameclass').css(...); // Not this way

$('#name<????>').css(...); // this way
```

How to do it?

Comment: Do u want to apply CSS to specific element or to group of elements who have ids in a range? like name1 to name10 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use an [attribute starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector:

```
$('[id^="name"]').css(...);
```

And if you need even more fine grained control over the selector you could [use regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions).

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is a `string`, so you can build the string by addition (+):

```
int id = 5;
$("#name"+ id).css(...);
```

But if you want to select multiple items, I would suggest doing this by class and not ID as ID's are meant for 1 item, classes are meant for a group of items.
You could do:

```
$(".nameclass").each(function() {
    if($(this).attr("id").contains("name")) {
        $(this).css(...);
    }
});
```