# How to target an image by part of its filename with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have several images on a site with filenames like `filename_mov.jpg`. The `filename` part is what is dynamically generated, e.g: `123456abc_mov.jpg`.

I want the target this by searching for part of the filename, as `_mov.jpg` is the only thing that’s consistent.

Using jQuery can I search for this?

I’ve tried:

```
$("img[src*='_mov.jpg']").addClass('movieThumb');
```

But it doesn’t work.

Comment: What have should work fine - why does it not work for you?

Comment: you'd need selectors with regular expressions - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions - but it may be just better to iterate through all images and check the src attribute value

Comment: In which way does it "not work"? The selector looks fine and would select an image with this URL: http://jsfiddle.net/j6cc2/

Comment: have you used a debugger to check the class is being applied - it may be that your styling is not working as expected

Comment: Thanks all for your replies. It was conflicting with a function further on in the script that stopped it working. Had me baffled for a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [the “attribute ends with” selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/):

```
$('img[src$="_mov.jpg"]').addClass('movieThumb');
```

Or you could do the filtering yourself using [`jQuery#filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$('img').filter(function() {
  return /_mov\.jpg$/.test(this.src);
}).addClass('movieThumb');
```

Comment: I ended up using this filter. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('img').each(function(){

    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    if(src.indexOf('_mov') != -1)
        //do stuff
});
```

Not sure how well indexof works on strings in IE though.

Comment: `$("img[src*='_mov.jpg']")` should work fine though... if that does not work, your could shouldn't either. But yes, `indexOf` works for strings in IE as well. *edit:* Your code is actually not correct. It  returns `true` if `indexOf` returns `-1` i.e. the substring was not found. It will probably be true for every image then.  You have to compare against `-1`: `if(this.src.indexOf(...) > -1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `$.filter`

```
$('img')
    .filter(function() {
        return this.src.match(/_mov\.jpg$/);
    })
.addClass('movieThumb');
;
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid fiddling with complicated selectors, I'd suggest adding a certain CSS class, like `<img class="mov_image" src="...._mov.jpg">`:

```
$('.mov_image').addClass('movieThumb');
```

Comment: adding a class to identify the elements he needs to add a class is an endless task.

Comment: This is not an uncommon use to [employ CSS classes to provide semantics](http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_Shopping_Cart_Annotating_Products.html) ([here is another one](http://microformats.org/2005/10/19/more-than-styling)).