# I need to find if a class exists in a div tag (catch is I only know part of the classname)

Tags: jquery, html, jsp-tags

I have 3 divs within a div container, I loop through each of them. I need to check if the classname matches a certain value. The catch is I know only part of the class name.

e.g.: I just used star wars as an example to illustrate my case.
All i know is my classname should be R2XX how do I retrieve R2D2 and R2D5 from the 3 mentioned below

```
<div class="DIV_HORZ"> --container div
    <div class="R2D5"></div>
    <div class="C3P0"></div>
    <div class="R2D2"></div>
</div>
```

**javascript part:**

```
$(".DIV_HORZ > div[id]").each(function(){
 ***find div whose class matches R2 + something***
});
```

Comment: regex is your friend!  

check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [attribute-starts-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```js
$('.DIV_HORZ > div[class^="R2"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the starts with selector, you could also use your `.each()` loop and use your own custom code including a regular expression if you wanted:

```
$(".DIV_HORZ > div[id]").each(function(){
    if (this.id.match(/^R2/) {
        // found a matching id, process the item here
    }
});
```

The regular expression or code can obviously be as involved as you want it to.  If needed, it can use more logic that just the built-in selector engine has.