# RegExp Wildcard Selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I got divs with IDs like that:

```
<div id="drop_12_213_1">
<div id="drop_12_213_2">
<div id="drop_12_213_3">
<div id="drop_13_213_4">
```

The only thing I know is `drop` and the `last number`(e.g. 1).

How can I select it whit jQuery?

`$('div[id^=drop_*_*_1]')` is not working?

What am I doing wrong?

TIA frgtv10

Comment: not that you can't do it, but wouldn't be possible for you to use css classes?

Comment: You might want to consider changing these to `<div class="drop" data-x="12" data-y="213" data-z="1">`, so that you can select them with `$('div.drop[data-z=1]')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery doesn't support regular expressions as selectors by default. There are some [filters](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/) that could do that.

What you can do instead is use the [jQuery `filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method.

```
$('div').filter(function() {
    return this.id.match(/^drop_\d+_\d+_1$/);
}).html("match");
```

This will basically check all the `div`s in your document and use the filter() method to see if it should match or not.
I imagine this will not be the fastest way of doing, you could try to restrict the search as much as possible (e.g. `$('div', container_of_divs)`), but by the looks of what you're trying to parse, it seems result is more important than speed.

As a note, your regular expression is wrong too.

`drop_*_*_1` translates to something like:

- `drop` followed by
- `_` zero or more times,
- `_` zero or more times,
- `_1`

Which would match something like `drop_1` or `drop__1` or `drop___`...`_1`.

Links:

- jsFiddle where I tried your sample: http://jsfiddle.net/3fXke/
- similar question on stackoverflow: [jQuery selector regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is it possible to add the number as an variable in the `match(/.../)` part?

Comment: You would want to build that regular expression dynamically in that case. I did something like that here: http://jsfiddle.net/3fXke/1/