# Select elements with rising numbers

Tags: jquery, select

I have a problem with jQuery. In my HTML Code I have some elements with rising numbers like this:

```
<ul class="flexer-0"> ... <ul class="flexer-1"> ... <ul class="flexer-2">
```

This classes the ul get with this code:

```
$('ul').addClass(function(index) {
    return 'flexer-' + index;
});
```

How am I able to select this elements later by jQuery.

My idea was like this:

```
$("ul.flexer-0") ...
$("ul.flexer-1") ...
$("ul.flexer-2") ...
```

This is stressful, because it will be become a long page with many ul-lists. It should be possible to get the index-number with jQuery.

Has anyone an idea?

Kai

Comment: Possibly useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `flexer-n` is the **only** class in the element's `class` attribute, you can use an [attribute starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector to select all matches:

```
$('ul[class^="flexer"]')
```

That will match any `ul` whose `class` attribute *starts with* `flexer`.

But note that it will not work if you have other classes on, for instance:

```
<ul class="foo flexer-3">
```

---

I'd take a step back and ask: Why do you have all of these `flexer-n` classes? It sounds like a single class, perhaps combined with `id`s or perhaps a [`data-*` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/global-attributes.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes) on the individual flexers, would make more sense.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try this. I also have another class in the ul. <ul class="slides flexer-0">, but now I make a workaround with your notes.