# How can I select an element by ID with jQuery using regex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following input elements:

```
<input id="AAA_RandomString_BBB" type="text" />
<input id="AAA_RandomString_BBB_Start" type="text" />
<input id="AAA_RandomString_BBB_End" type="text" />
```

AAA & BBB are constants and I will always know what they are.  However RandomString will always be random.

I want to get the value of AAA_RandomString_BBB.  I do not want the values from the input elements with ID ending in either _Start or _End.

I tried the folowing:

```
$('[id^="AAA_"]')
```

But the above selects all of the input elements that have an ID starting with "AAA_"

I need some way to select using a regex type syntax like:

```
$('[id^="AAA_(.+?)_BBB"]')
```

Is this possible? If not, can anyone suggest a method of selecting

Answer (score 134, accepted):

You can combine both selectors in a [multiple attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/).

```
​$("[id^=AAA_][id$=_BBB]")
```

It will return all the elements that matches all the specified attribute filters:

- [`[id^=AAA_]`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) matches elements with `id` attribute starting with `AAA_`, and
- [`[id$=_BBB]`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) matches elements with `id` attribute ending with `_BBB`.

---

Another generic alternatives:

- Using a [custom `:regex()` selector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/190255/417685),
- Using a [`.filter()`-based approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/193787/417685).

Answer (score 17):

#### Use this:

```
$('[id^="AAA_"][id$="_BBB"]')
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/J6hGx/

Answer (score 8):

You can look for id's starting with `AAA` and ending with `BBB` like this:

```
​$("[id^=AAA_][id$=_BBB]")
```

The working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DN9uV/

Answer (score 8):

This can be done like so:

```
$('input').filter(function(){ return this.id.match(/^AAA_.+_BBB$/) })
```

You can give use `$('input', <context>)` to make the search more precise.
See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

I use to solve this with the class selectors which don't need to be unique.

This also has a positive effect on speed because no complex search is required
Additionally you can use this for the different styling of different elements

e.g.

```
<elem id="1" class="aa">element type aa</elem>
<elem id="2" class="aa">element type aa</elem>
<elem id="3" class="aa bb">element type aa and bb</elem>
<elem id="4" class="bb">element type bb</elem>
```

Now you can simply use the class selector

```
$('.aa').click(function(){
     console.log( 'clicked type aa #' + $(this).attr('id') );
});

$('.bb').click(function(){
     console.log( 'clicked type bb #' + $(this).attr('id') );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to just check for the id ending on _BBB by

```
 $("[id$=_BBB]")
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="AAA_RandomString_BBB" type="text" />
        <input id="AAA_RandomString_BBB_Start" type="text" />
        <input id="AAA_RandomString_BBB_End" type="text" />

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                debugger
                var targetElement = $('input')
                .filter(function () {
                    var el = this.id.match(/^AAA.*BBB$/g);
                    return el;
                });
                console.log(targetElement.val());
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```