# Jquery Selector using ID Regex or redundant Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, regex

There are a group of ***similar*** elements with ***similiar*** IDs

Here are two ways to using Jquery to select them:

1. ID + Regex (Example: [How can I select an element by ID with jQuery using regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541898/how-can-i-select-an-element-by-id-with-jquery-using-regex))
2. Add a redundant class to all the elements, then select the class

Here is the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/J6hGx/31/

Which approach is better? Is `ID+Regex` more time-consuming?

Comment: RegEx is not a natively supported selector. So it would be faster if you use classes to group similar elements.

Comment: Is this really a performance bottleneck ?

Comment: @t.niese Sure but this class is **redundant**.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus No. I just want to know which approach is better?

Comment: It's not a regex, that is the "attribute starts with" selector, that does have a "regex like" syntax.

Comment: So I would go for redundancy : same elements with same behavior makes things clear for every reader. But that's just a point of view...

Comment: @adeneo You mean this?http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp But this is CSS3 which is still under development.

Comment: No, I mean [**this**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/), which is what you're using in the fiddle, I'm just saying it's not a selector that accepts regular expression, it's a specific selector called *"the attribute starts with selector"*, it's not regex.

Answer (score 0):

You will get better performance using classes than selectors.

In the DOM, whatever has more specificity will be better. Having unused classes does not frustrate the rendering engine.

Finally, using specific classes increases readability of the code.

Comment: This is wrong, classes are selectors in this context, and specificity has nothing to do with javascript performance. Wether or not the selector can be used directly by native methods or in querySelector is important, and in older browsers, classes are shite for performance as IE didn't support getElementsByClassName or querySelectorAll until recently (IE8 for QSA).

Comment: You are right. But would the DOM API have an easier time querying by `getElementsByClassName` versus `querySelectorAll`?

Comment: No, not really, but in IE7 and below there's no option for classes at all, so jQuery has to iterate over all the elements in the DOM and check the className for each element, so in those browsers just about anything would be faster, but targeting by attribute does somewhat the same if queryselector isn't supported, so it would be the same thing.