# Iterate all elements and change their id

Tags: jquery, html, jsp

I have a .jsp page where many elements have ids that end with a certain string. For example:

```
<div id="topActions-1083"></div>
<div id="collapse-1083">
<input id="collapse1Input-1083" type="hidden" value="expanded"></input>
</div>
```

Which is the fastest way to get all elements with id ending in '1083' and change it to '1084' ?

Comment: In first place, do you really need to use IDs?

Comment: Read [How can I select an element by ID with jQuery using regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541898/how-can-i-select-an-element-by-id-with-jquery-using-regex)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use the `.attr()`'s receiver function,

```
$('[id$=1083]').attr('id',function(_,id){ 
    return id.substr(id.length - 4) + '1084'; 
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/63e7t/1/)

Or as wolf suggested you could use `.split()` instead of `.substring()`

```
$('[id$=1083]').attr("id", function (_, id) {   
   return id.split('-')[0] + '-1084';
});
```

Comment: You should split it instead: `$('[id$=1083]').attr("id", function (_, id) {
    return id.split('-')[0] + '-1084';
});`

Comment: @A.Wolff Yeah.. that also a possible solution.. i'll include that.

Comment: Wolff's comment was really useful because the ending string (here '1083') may not always be of the same size.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
$("[id*=1083]").each(function(){
   var iid = $(this).attr('id')
   var fin = iid.replace('1083','1084')
   $(this).attr('id',fin)
   console.log(fin)
});
```

[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nQzz8/)

**Selectors Example** :

Starts with a given string (for example 1083),

```
$("[id^='1083']")
```

If you want to select elements which id contains a given string :

```
$("[id*='1083']")
```

If you want to select elements which id is not a given string :

```
$("[id!='1083']")
```

Answer (score 1):

You may possibly try this:

**script**

```
$(function()
{
    $('[id$=1083]').prop('id',function()
    {
        return this.id.replace('1083', '1084');
    });
});
```