# get fieldset that contains the word Target

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div>
<fieldset id='dynamicTargetId'>
<legend>test</legend>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

What's the best way using jQuery to get the fieldset that contains the word Target. The Id will be a composite that always contains the word Target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the CSS attribute selectors:

```
​$("fieldset[id*=Target]")
```

In general, `[att*=str]` matches any attribute value that contains str anywhere within it.

Here is an example:

```js
var test = $('fieldset[id*=Target]');
$('#count').text(test.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<fieldset id='dynamicTargetId'>
<legend>test</legend>
</fieldset>
  <fieldset id='anotherTargetId'>
<legend>test</legend>
</fieldset>
  <fieldset id='TargetId'>
<legend>test</legend>
</fieldset>
</div>
<p>
  Found <span id="count"></span> fieldset elements containing 'Target'
</p>
```

If you need to match attributes that contain values at a certain position (beginning or end), you can use something like:

```
[att^=str]     // attribute value starting with str

[att$=str]     // attribute value ends with str
```

[More details about different attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)

[Other possible ways of performing the matching you need](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13541938/3928341)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) on the `id` attribute. For example:

```
$("fieldset[id*='Target']");
```