# Select element with complex ID pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have set of buttons like this:

```
<button id="grid1_createBtn">Create</button>
<button id="grid1_updateBtn">Update</button>
<button id="grid2_createBtn">Create</button>
...
```

These button does not have any class, so I need to select them via their ID. The "grid" part of id is static and same for all buttons. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13541938/1531130), but I don't want to use `​$("[id^=grid]")`, because may be some other other element with starting id "grid" exist. Can anyone help me?

Comment: do something like this ​$(".parentClass > [id^=grid]")

Comment: so why you can not assign the class instead?

Comment: Are all buttons start with `grid` also end with `Btn`?

Comment: As @MirzaDanishBaig suggests can you not add the class? It would be the simplest option and reduce your selector to: `$('button.something')`

Answer (score 6):

To select the buttons with a regular expression, you may use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) like this :

```
$('button').filter(function(){
    return /^grid\d+_\w+Btn$/.test(this.id)
})
```

Comment: I never think about using filter, despite this being super-neat and super-powerful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var id= 1;
$("button[id*='grid" + id+ "_createBtn']");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also combine attribute selectors like below as long as all your buttons start with `grid` and end with `Btn`.

```
$('button[id^="grid"][id$="Btn"]')
```

[**-A Demo-**](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/ohjdd8u1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can combine!

```
$("[id^='grid'][id$='Btn']")

$("[id^='grid'][id$='Btn'][id*='_']")
```

or you can mix with Denis Seguret aproach

```
$("button[id^='grid']").filter( 
    function(){
        return /^grid\d+_(create|update)Btn$/.test(this.id);
    }
)
```

this is faster than only the filter.