# getElementsByName: control by last partial name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can get div elements by id and using only partial name "first"

html

```
<div id="first.1.end">first.1.end</div>
<div id="first.2.end">first.2.end</div>
<div id="two.3.end">two.3.end</div>
<div id="first.4.end">first.4.end</div>
```

js

```
function getElementsByIdStartsWith(selectorTag, prefix) {
    var items = [];
    var myPosts = document.getElementsByTagName(selectorTag);
    for (var i = 0; i < myPosts.length; i++) {
        if (myPosts[i].id.lastIndexOf(prefix, 0) === 0) {
            items.push(myPosts[i]);
        }
    }
    return items;
}
var postedOnes = getElementsByIdStartsWith("div", "first");
alert(postedOnes.length);
```

It counts 3 div elements (alert).

But how can I use end-partial name for search? For example using "end"?

Comment: so you want to search by "end" instead of "first"?

Comment: see below ans hope that will help you...  that is a common function which include combination or all three params..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [MDN Attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

> [attr^=value] Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and
>   whose value is prefixed by "value".
>
> [attr$=value] Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and
>   whose value is suffixed by "value".

So you can use `[id^="first"]` to find elements with id start with `"first"`. and use `[id$="end"]` to find elements end with `"end"`.

Like

```
// This find all div which id ends with "end".
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div[id$="end"]');
```

or use jQuery:

```
$('div[id$="end"]');
```

Also, you can combine multiple attribute selectors altogether to find a more specific element:

```
// As we only use querySelector, it find the first div with id starts with "two" and ends with "end".
var divStartAndEnd = document.querySelector('div[id^="two"][id$="end"]');
```

See demo on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jyydscht/4/)

Answer (score 1):

I guess this kind of selection can be possible by using jQuery + regex. Have a look to this

[How can I select an element by ID with jQuery using regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541898/how-can-i-select-an-element-by-id-with-jquery-using-regex)

Might be some what on the line that you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here I am allowing user to pass all three parameters.
suppose user doesn't pass midmatch so it will return only match of first and last.

***Below is the working code:***

**It will return 1 count:**

```
function getElementsByIdStartsWith(selectorTag, firstmatch, midmatch, lastmatch) {
    var items = [];
    var myPosts = document.getElementsByTagName(selectorTag);
    for (var i = 0; i < myPosts.length; i++) {
        var firstmatchIndex = firstmatch?myPosts[i].id.indexOf(firstmatch)>-1?true : false : true;
        var midmatchIndex = midmatch?myPosts[i].id.indexOf(midmatch)>-1?true : false : true;
        var lastmatchIndex = lastmatch?myPosts[i].id.indexOf(lastmatch)>-1?true : false : true;
        if (firstmatchIndex && midmatchIndex && lastmatchIndex  ) {
            items.push(myPosts[i]);
        }
    }
    return items;
}
var postedOnes = getElementsByIdStartsWith("div", "first", "2", "end");
alert(postedOnes.length); // now it will show only one in alert.
```

**It will return 3 count:**

```
function getElementsByIdStartsWith(selectorTag, firstmatch, midmatch, lastmatch) {
    var items = [];
    var myPosts = document.getElementsByTagName(selectorTag);
    for (var i = 0; i < myPosts.length; i++) {
        var firstmatchIndex = firstmatch?myPosts[i].id.indexOf(firstmatch)>-1?true : false : true;
        var midmatchIndex = midmatch?myPosts[i].id.indexOf(midmatch)>-1?true : false : true;
        var lastmatchIndex = lastmatch?myPosts[i].id.indexOf(lastmatch)>-1?true : false : true;
        if (firstmatchIndex && midmatchIndex && lastmatchIndex  ) {
            items.push(myPosts[i]);
        }
    }
    return items;
}
var postedOnes = getElementsByIdStartsWith("div", "first", "", "end");
alert(postedOnes.length); // now it will show only three in alert.
```

if you don't want to consider any parameter just pass empty string( **""** )  while calling the function.

Hope this will help you :)