# Jquery [attribute] Selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I've seen several posts explaining how to use a variable in a value for attribute selection. i.e. (where the JS event refers to the div (making it $(this):

**HTML**

```
<div id="item1"></div>
<div id="item1" style="display: none;"></div>
```

**JS**

```
var find = $(this).attr("id")
$('div[id="'+find+'"]').show();
```

But I would like to know how to use a variable in a jquery selector to find something with a similar string to the value of the variable. i.e. finding an element from the example above but looking for "#item1div", where the event target is still "#item1"

**HTML**

```
<div id="item1"></div>
<div id="item1div" style="display: none;"></div>
```

**JS**

```
var find = $(this).attr("id")
$('div[id="'+find+"div"'"]').show(); // incorrect syntax
```

**So my question is: How do I correct the above syntax to include an additional string in the attribute check?**

I can't find any reference to the correct syntax for how to add compile a string of the value of a variable and an explicit string then check that as the value for x attribute.

I know I can use `[id*="'+find+'"]` here because the alternate id contains the same characters as the basic one, but I want to know how to target a specific other id based on the first one. For example if I had #item1, #item1div, and #item1img, how can I use an event on "#item1" to find attribute values equal to "item1div" and/or "item1img"

**EDIT:** I also just realized I can just use `[id|="'+find+'"]` if I name the divs accordingly with hyphens, but again doesn't solve ids with different endings (or different strings that come after the hyphen)

Comment: You should use ID selector `$('#' + find).show()` instead of `$('.Divs[id="'+find+'"]').show();`. So you can use `$('#' + find + 'div')` to find `#item1div` or anything dynamic on the first part. Note: the incorrect you had mentioned is because of a missing `+` - It should be `$('div[id="'+find+"div" **+**'"]').show();`

Comment: the question is very unclear. what are you trying to do? do a wildcard search ?

Comment: here are some ideas:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541898/how-can-i-select-an-element-by-id-with-jquery-using-regex

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions

Comment: The error is here : `"div"'"]'` you only need to write `"div"]'` but you shouldn't select ids that way. Use `'#' + find` instead. Also, this might help: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: If I have understand the question clearly, then see my answer if it helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('div[id="'+find+"div"'"]')` isn't valid *Javascript* syntax:

```
$(          // jQuery function
'div[id="'  // String
+ find      // Add variable
+ "div"     // Add String
'"]'        // Unexpected string! - Error
```

One example of valid syntax would be:

```
$('div[id="'+find+'div"]')
```

However, since it's an id, you can use the id selector instead:

```
$('div#'+find+'div')
```

Comment: This was very helpful, as were most everyone comments and answers. But I really appreciate the breakdown of what my syntax what doing and where it went wrong. I'm learning more javascript everyday and sometimes I feel like my syntax is close but can't quite figure out what I'm missing or leaving out. Also, to appease the javascript experts I am now trying to use the proper `('#'+var+)` to select ids - I didn't realize this was used as a selector specifically for id's. No wonder I couldnt find anything on `[id="` Thanks Again.

Comment: @RobertH Both ways [should work](http://jsfiddle.net/c3j8zLww/2/). The `#` syntax is just shorter and usually easier to read. There are also subtle differences too; if your selector only uses `#` (e.g., `$("#someId")`), then the selector engine can optimize it and it will only retrieve the first instance.

Answer (score 0):

the question is very unclear, but I assume your question boils down to :

**Q**:how do you search all the elements where it starts with string `x` ?

**A**:To get all the elements starting with "item1" you should use:

`$("[id^=item1]")`

Comment: Sorry, I try to include all the details and things I've thought of trying to be as clear about how far I am into the problem solve.

The question boils down to how do I correctly use: `$('div[id="'+find+"div"'"]').show(); // incorrect syntax`
to input the value of a variable in an attribute check, but then add something additional to that string that the variable equates to (like adding "div" to "item1")

Answer (score 0):

You should use ID selector like below to find an element by ID,

```
$('#' + find).show();
```

To find item1div or the dynamic first part -  `$('#' + find + 'div')`

**Note**: the incorrect syntax you had mentioned is because of a missing `+` - It should be

```
//                     V-- you missed this
$('div[id="'+find+"div"+'"]').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

To add the explicit string to the attr value you can write as follows

```
$('[attr="'+attrVal+'extraString"]')
```

For evample in case of id of div itemdiv

```
var item1ID = $('#item1').attr('id');   // item1
$('[id="'+item1ID+'div"]')              // valid selector to select #item1div
```