# Use other tags for use with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, show

My question it´s about if it´s possble use other tags, not only id or class,  i explain, for example always use :

```
jQuery(".class or other name")

jQuery("#div or other name")
```

This it´s the most clear case when use jQuery but how i can use jQuery without use class or id, for example :

```
<div act="loggin">Show Me</div>
```

In this case the tag it´s **act** and in the normal case i can show this div using jQuery in this way :

```
jQuery("#loggin").show(1000);
```

But if i use act as tag and don´t use id or class how i can use jQuery over this div for show

I hope understand the question, thank´s regards

Comment: There are dozens of ways to find elements. I suggest starting with the official documentation: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: One appropriate use for down-voting on this site is for questions that do not show any research effort. I down-voted because I think this could have been addressed outside of [so] if you had just done some more research. jQuery is a famous library with really good documentation.

Comment: `"And do you know if i search or no ?, Who are you for speak about my effort or no effort...."` -- all anyone can use to judge this is what you've posted in your question, but that's all that is needed. Simply show the *concrete* fruits of your own research in your question itself, and this would be a moot point.

Comment: Please read: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) for more of the details of this site's standing on this. Don't worry, you'll get the hang of this over time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery \[attribute\] Selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32255569/jquery-attribute-selectors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an attribute selector

For specific attribute and value:

```
$('[act="loggin"]')
```

Or for all elements with a specific attribute with any value:

```
$('[act]')
```

There are a multitude of wildcards you can also use. See [jQuery Attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)