# Dynamically selecting elements using jquery mulitple selector attribute

Tags: jquery

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541898/how-can-i-select-an-element-by-id-with-jquery-using-regex), I am trying to bind a `keydow` event handler on all dynamically elements which id starts with `id_phone-` and finished with `-value`. For example, `id_phone-3-value` should math, whereas `id-phone-3-value` should not.

To achieve this, I tried to come up with the code below:

```
$(document).on('keydown', '[id^=id_phone-_][id$=_-value]', function(){
   console.log('test');
});
```

...which, unfortunately, does not work for me. What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `_` in your selectors. Your selector will match something like `id_phone-_3_-value`, but the IDs you want to match don't have underscores around the number.

```js
$(document).on('keydown', '[id^=id_phone-][id$=-value]', function(){
   console.log('test');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
This should trigger: <input id="id_phone-3-value" type="text"><br>
This should not trigger: <input id="id-phone-3-value" type="text">
```