# JQuery check with regex and add class

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

In my HTML there are number of divs each having names inside. I have to implement alphabetic filter in it. If user clicks on button 'A-J' the list will make only divs where first letter of name is between A-J and similarly for other letter groups.
I have written following piece of code till now :

```
        $("#jfmfs-filter-selected-aj").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            for (i = 0; i < all_friends.length ; i++)
            {
                var aFriend = $( all_friends[i] );
                if(!(/^[a-jA-J]+$/.test(aFriend.find(".friend-name").html().charAt(0)))){
                    aFriend.addClass("hide-filtered");
                }
            }
            $(".filter-link").removeClass("selected");
            $(this).addClass("selected");
        });
```

This Code works fine but hides div in a loop and hence it takes time. Is there a way i can write the above code in single line to add "hide-filtered" class to all divs which meets my criteria in one go Something like this?

```
all_friends.not( {divs with inner html starting with letters a-j} ).addClass("hide-non-selected");
all_friends.not( /^[a-jA-J]+$/.test(all_friends.find(".friend-name").html().charAt(0)) ).addClass("hide-non-selected");
```

Final Solution I used using jquery filter (Barmar's answer):

```
all_friends.filter(function() {
                      return(!(/^[a-fA-F]+$/.test($(this).find(".friend-name").html().charAt(0))))
                    }).addClass("hide-non-selected");
```

Comment: Looks like [this][1] is the kind of stuff you're looking for..


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions

Comment: @AidanEwen jQuery regex selectors can only be applied to attributes, not to text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var AJ_regex = /^[a-jA-J]/;
$('.friend-name', aFriend).filter(function() {
    return !(AJ_regex.test($(this).html()));
}).addClass("hide-filtered");
```

Comment: Thanks I have updated my question with the final solution I used.

Comment: The simplest and biggest efficiency saving you could make is to create the regular expression outside the loop (and `.filter()` is effectively a loop).

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot Thanks for the suggestion, I made that change to my answer. This also suggests that if he has different filters, he could use a single function and pass the RE as a parameter.

Comment: By the way, your solution (before moving the regexp out of the loop), although concise, is probably *less* efficient than the OP's original in that it loops three times - once to apply the selector, once to filter, and once to apply the class. Only the first is a big deal. On efficiency grounds, it is better to use a preformed collection rather than make a new one, especially when making/changing the selection involves the DOM.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot That's probably true of many chained jQuery operations, since each step in the chain is another loop over the collection, and this is a common idiom. It's not usually a problem if the collection is small.

Comment: Indeed Barmar, all these issues can be safely ignored for small collections.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [jquery filter by James Padolsey](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/). It looks like you could use this to do the kind of thing you're looking for.

For your purposes it would look something like -

```
$('div.friend-name').filter('div:regex(innerHTML, ^[a-jA-J])').addClass("hide-non-selected");
```

(that will probably need tweaking - I've not tested it).