# jQuery match part of class with hasClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

I have several div's with "project[0-9]" classes:

```
<div class="project1"></div>
<div class="project2"></div>
<div class="project3"></div>
<div class="project4"></div>
```

I want to check if the element has a "project[0-9]" class. I have `.hasClass("project")` but I'm stuck with matching numbers.

Any idea?

Comment: Why don't you just give them one class `project`?

Comment: @Bergi There are moments when you can't. The answer below helped me because I can only inject my own javascript in the page I'm working on, not change the html itself.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can use the [startswith CSS3 selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to get those divs:

```
$('div[class^="project"]')
```

To check one particular element, you'd use [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/), not `hasClass`:

```
$el.is('[class^="project"]')
```

For using the exact `/project\d/` regex, you can check out [jQuery selector regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/190253/1048572) or use

```
/(^|\s)project\d(\s|$)/.test($el.attr("class"))
```

Comment: So something like: if($(this) == $('div[class^="project"]')) ??

Comment: Note that the startwith select will not work if `projectN` is not the first class name of the element, say `class="someclass project1"`. So the last regex version should be used in this case.

Answer (score 14):

A better approach for your html would be:
I believe these div's share some common properties.

```
<div class="project type1"></div>
<div class="project type2"></div>
<div class="project type3"></div>
<div class="project type4"></div>
```

Then you can find them using:

```
$('.project')
```

Answer (score 11):

```
$('div[class*="project"]')
```

will not fail with something like this:

```
<div class="some-other-class project1"></div>
```

Comment: but it will also fire on `<div class='some-other-project-class'>`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div[class^="project"]')
```

will fail with something like this:

```
<div class="some-other-class project1"></div>
```

Here is an alternative which extends jQuery:

```
// Select elements by testing each value of each element's attribute `attr` for `pattern`.

  jQuery.fn.hasAttrLike = function(attr, pattern) {

    pattern = new RegExp(pattern)
    return this.filter(function(idx) {
      var elAttr = $(this).attr(attr);
      if(!elAttr) return false;
      var values = elAttr.split(/\s/);
      var hasAttrLike = false;
      $.each(values, function(idx, value) {
        if(pattern.test(value)) {
          hasAttrLike = true;
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      });
      return hasAttrLike;
    });
  };



jQuery('div').hasAttrLike('class', 'project[0-9]')
```

original from sandinmyjoints: https://github.com/sandinmyjoints/jquery-has-attr-like/blob/master/jquery.hasAttrLike.js 
(but it had errrors so I fixed it)

Answer (score 0):

You can improve the existing `hasClass` method:

```js
// This is all that you need:
(orig => { 
  jQuery.fn.hasClass = function(className) {
    return className instanceof RegExp
      ? this.attr('class') && this.attr('class')
        .split(/\s+/)
        .findIndex(name => className.test(name)) >= 0
      : orig.call(this, className); 
  }
})(jQuery.fn.hasClass);

// Test the new method:
Boolean.prototype.toString = function(){ this === true ? 'true' : 'false' };
const el = $('#test');
el.append("hasClass('some-name-27822'): " + el.hasClass('some-name-27822'));
el.append("\nhasClass(/some-name-\d+/): " + el.hasClass(/some-name-\d+/));
el.append("\nhasClass('anothercoolclass'): " + el.hasClass('anothercoolclass'));
el.append("\nhasClass(/anothercoolclass/i): " + el.hasClass(/anothercoolclass/i));
el.append("\nhasClass(/^-name-/): " + el.hasClass(/^-name-/));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="test" class="some-name-0 some-name-27822 another-some-name-111 AnotherCoolClass"></pre>
```

Answer (score -7):

why don't you use for to check numbers

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                if(....hasClass("project"+i))
                {
            //do what you need
                }
            }
```