# jQuery how to get complete class name with hasClass

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to check the complete class name using `hasClass()` function in jQuery. I have class named "Disclaimer"

```
  <div id="fakeform1">
  <div class="Disclaimer"> I want to get complete class name 
  </div></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function({     
   if($('#fakeform1').hasClass('sclaimer')==0) {
      alert(COMPLETE CLASS NAME);
    }
  ));
</script>
```

How I get the complete name of `sclaimer` class which is Disclaimer ?

Comment: `$('#fakeform1')[0].className` - or `$('#fakeform1').attr('class')` if you must

Comment: though, looking at your code ... `hasClass('sclaimer')` wont find an element with class `Disclaimer` anyway

Comment: Please add you HTML PART for more clearance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery match part of class with hasClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13878759/jquery-match-part-of-class-with-hasclass)

Comment: alert shows UNDEFINED

Comment: question update with HTML PART

Answer (score 0):

you can't use `hasClass` for that case, try this:

```
if ($('#fakeform1').attr('class').indexOf('sclaimer') !== -1) {
    alert($('#fakeform1').attr('class'));
}
```

**EDIT:**

Looks like I misunderstand your question, if you want to check the children element, then try this one:

```
var test = $('#fakeform1').find('div').filter(function() { return $(this).attr('class').indexOf('sclaimer') !== -1; });
if (test.length) {
    alert(test.attr('class'));
}
```

**fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/zjq5u2vL/

Comment: @MuhammadKazim my bad, I fixed it. use "-1" instead of "1"

Comment: @MuhammadKazim I fixed my answer, I also include fiddle, try that one :)