# Parse classname for number at end?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have elements. I know for sure they will have a class 'fc-id#' where '#' is a number.

I need to somehow get that number. This will always be the first class of the element.

Is there some way to get the number at the end?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions for a start.

Comment: Like: `var cls = element.className.split(' ')[0]; var num = cls.match(/fc-id(\d)/)[1];`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("[class^=fc-id]").each(function(){
      var num = this.className.split(' ')[0].match(/fc-id(\d)/)[1];
});
```

[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/LdPaw/0)

Answer (score 0):

use `.split()` method like

```
var idNum = $(this).attr('class').split('id')[1]; // #
```

or if you need to retrieve the first class do like:

```
var idNum = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0].split('id')[1]; // #
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("[class^=fc-id]").each(function(){
    // Everything after the first 5 characters (fc-id)
    alert($(this).attr("class").substring(5)); 
})
```

Comment: If the element has multiple classes, this will return the rest of them as well.