# Getting all the elements containing numeric data from a webpage using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering, **is there any way that I can get all the elements i.e. `div`s `span`s etc containing the numeric data?** What I want to do is get all of them and then format them using a currency formatter jquery plugin. The code that I'm using now is:

```
var options = {
    symbol: "",
    decimal: ".",
    thousand: ",",
    precision: 2,
    format: "%s%v"
};

$(".namount").each(function () {
    var formattedNum = accounting.formatMoney($(this).text(), options)
    $(this).html(formattedNum);
});

$(".totalsale").each(function(){
    var formattedNum = accounting.formatMoney($(this).text(), options)
    $(this).html(formattedNum);
});

$(".totalpurchase").each(function(){
    var formattedNum = accounting.formatMoney($(this).text(), options)
    $(this).html(formattedNum);
});
```

There are 4 to 5 more similar calls to `each` loop for different elements. The problem is, doing this won't be efficient. Is there any other way that I can achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a class selector this is one of the best ways. Only change I would do is to use a [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) and the use the [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-functionindex--text) method to update the value in the element

```
$(".namount, .totalsale, .totalpurchase").text(function (idx, text) {
    return accounting.formatMoney(text, options)
});
```

Another possible change you can think of is to narrow down the search context using a parent container element

Comment: Thanks for your answer but isn't there any other way that I can select **all the elements containing numeric values** ?

Comment: @KamranAhmed no there is not, next solution is to go through all the elements and check whether they are numeric, that is a lot costlier

Comment: Hmmm
I've used your solution for the time being however let me wait for some other answers, but I'm pretty sure that I'll be selecting your answer as the chosen one ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using class selector as suggested or you can achieve this using regular expression too.

Refer this

[jQuery selector regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions)

Comment: cost of this will be too high as there are no native support for this, if a class selector is used then the native support for selecting elements by class name will be used which will be much faster than any other method