# How to use multiple attribute selectors but for/with specific attribute values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, attributes

I am using jQuery and I have the following HTML code:

```
<a href="/link" data-a='{"one":"sample1","two":"sample2"}' data-b="true">Title</a>
```

I would like to find the above link by using [multiple attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/) but for/with specific values contained in `data-*` attributes. That is, I can find the above link this way

```
selector = 'a[data-a][data-b]'
$(selector).bind(...)
```

but I would like to be more specific by finding links having `data-a` and `data-b` attributes and whose attribute `data-a` contains the `one` key.

How can I do that?

Comment: No, parsing the content of attributes is out of the scope of [attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors). You need to do that manually.

Comment: @Bergi - If so, how can/should I improve the code and the related selector?

Comment: you can try using the `*=` operator like this `a[data-a*='"one"'][data-b] {...}`

Comment: I'm afraid that the HTML code you edited is not a well-formed JSON string, it should be `data-a='{"one":"sample1","two":"sample2"}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing the content of attributes is out of the scope of [attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors). You need to do that manually, by [filtering](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) the selected elements:

```
$('a[data-a][data-b]').filter(function() {
    try {
        return "one" in JSON.parse($(this).attr("data-a"));
    } catch(e) {
        return false;
    }
}).on(…)
```

You could of course [implement a custom selector](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/extending-jquerys-selector-capabilities/) (or [use a regex selector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/190253/1048572)<sup>1</sup>), but that won't make much difference. And might dramatically decrease performance.

<sub>1: Uh, better not on JSON.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

This will work, but does not guarantee data-a is valid json lol

```
select = 'a[data-a*=\'"one":"\'][data-b]';
```

using the 'contains' selector: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Answer (score 0):

we can `.filter()` the first set of collection to ensure whether the element's data-* attribute contains the particular key.

You can do like this,

```
$('a[data-a][data-b]').filter(function(){
 return 'key' in JSON.parse($(this).data('a'));
}).bind(..)
```