# jQuery selector regex and getting the expression

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-selectors

I saw the issue [jQuery selector regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions) and I'm trying to use it but is there a way to get the class?

I'm using the regex in `$(.*class).change(function(){ I need to get the class here })`

I've seen the `.attr('class')` but I need to get the div.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so in the function(){ } using $(this) give you the div that was changed so you can apply the  `.attr('class')`