# How can I avoid writing 10 functions, make it just one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

EDIT: Thanks, but those answers are not the best way to do it and are difficult to understand by a beginner.

I have this structure:

```
<div>Title <a href="#" onclick="a1()">+</a>
<div id="b1">...content...</div></div>

..... n times this structure ....

<div>Title <a href="#" onclick="function aN()">+</a>
<div id="bN">...content...</div></div>
```

When the user clicks the + sign the content should show or disappear.

```
    function a1(){
            $('#b1').toggle(); 
    }

     .... too many functions .....

    function aN(){
            $('#bN').toggle(); 
    }
```

How can I rewrite all those functions in one single function to write less code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions

Comment: Whenever you have something like this, the first step you can do is make the thing that's different in each function (in your case the selector), a **parameter** of the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [abstract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_(computer_science)) your code by using a generalized class to hook your javascript to.  [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/b681zeLt/)

---

HTML

```
<div>
    Title <a href="#" class="toggleNext">+</a>
    <div id="b1">...content...</div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.toggleNext').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next().toggle()
});
```

Comment: You probably won't even need the id in the content div anymore.

Comment: Thanks! this is the cleanest way to do it.

Answer (score 6):

You can just make it more descriptive int he markup itself , use a custom attribute `data-target` (or use the href itself) and store the id of the target.

```
<div>Title <a data-target="#b1" class="toggler" href="#">+</a>
<div id="b1">...content...</div></div>

..... n times this structure ....

<div>Title <a data-target="#b2" class="toggler" href="#" >+</a>
<div id="bN">...content...</div></div>
```

and just register a function:-

```
$(function(){
   $('.toggler').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $($(this).data('target')).toggle();
   });
});
```

This way you can put any selector for the target in the attribute, regardless of wherever it appears in your markup (*Not just the next element*), and move away from the inline click handlers.

Comment: +1 - Nice way not to rely on markup structure and still using a performant selector.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried?

```
<div>Title <a href="#" onclick="a('b1')">+</a>
<div id="b1">...content...</div></div>

..... n times this structure ....

<div>Title <a href="#" onclick="a('bN')">+</a>
<div id="bN">...content...</div></div>

 function a(id){
            $('#' + id).toggle(); 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! It works well, but Brian's answer is cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="container">Title <a href="#" class="link">+</a>
<div class="content">...content...</div></div>

..... n times this structure ....

<div class="container">Title <a href="#" class="link">+</a>
<div class="content">...content...</div></div>

<script>
    $(".container .link").bind('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $(this).parent().find('.content').toggle();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, using inline event handlers is considered bad form for a variety of reasons.

That said, there are a few ways to do what you like.  Personally, I would go for this approach:

```
<div>Title <a href="#" onclick="toggleThing()" data-thing-to-toggle="b1">+</a>
<div id="b1">...content...</div></div>


function toggleThing() {
  var toggleId = this.getAttribute("data-thing-to-toggle");
  var $target = $(toggleId);
  $target.toggle();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a dummy class to all + anchor. e.g. anc

Then

```
$('.anc').on('click', function (){
   $(this).next('div').toggle();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/d1xpghrL/)

HTML: Using a CSS class

```
<div>Title <a href="#" class="myanchor">+</a>
<div id="b1">...content...</div></div>

<!--..... n times this structure ....-->

<div>Title <a href="#" class="myanchor">+</a>
<div id="bN">...content...</div></div>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    $('a.myanchor').on('click', a);
    function a(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).next('div').toggle();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's `on` method:

HTML:

```
<div>Title <a href="#" class="toggle">+</a>
<div class="content">...content...</div></div>
<div>Title <a href="#" class="toggle">+</a>
<div class="content">...content...</div></div>
<div>Title <a href="#" class="toggle">+</a>
<div class="content">...content...</div></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).on('click', '.toggle', function(e) {
    $(e.currentTarget).parent().find('.content').toggle();
});
```

Working jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/uq1mafs3/

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is passing the id of the element:

```
function a(id) {
    $('#' + id).toggle();
}
```

Your HTML would look like this:

```
<div>Title <a href="#" onclick="a('b1');">+</a>
<div id="b1">...content...</div></div>

..... n times this structure ....

<div>Title <a href="#" onclick="a('bN');">+</a>
<div id="bN">...content...</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pass the id of the element to be toggled as a function parameter:

```
<div>Title <a href="#" onclick="toggle('#b1')">+</a>
<div id="b1">...content...</div></div>

..... n times this structure ....

<div>Title <a href="#" onclick="toggle('#bN')">+</a>
<div id="bN">...content...</div></div>
```

Then you can implement just one function:

```
function toggle(id){
        $(id).toggle(); 
}
```

See [JavaScript Function Parameters](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp) for more information.