# jquery find a selector whose id contains a string using regex

Tags: jquery, regex

I want to match input fields that match the following pattern:

a_profile_contact_attributes_addresses_attributes_0_address
b_store_contact_attributes_addresses_attributes_3_address
somethingelse_contact_attributes_addresses_attributes_44_address

In other words, I want to use the following regex:

```
/contact_attributes_addresses_attributes_\d+_address/
```

Using jQuery, I tried the following but it returns an empty result set:

```
$('input[id*="contact_attributes_addresses_attributes_' + /\d+/ + '_address"]')
```

What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use jquery filter to filter out based on your needs, like below:

```
$('input').filter(function() {
    return this.id.match(/contact_attributes_addresses_attributes_\d+_address/i)
}).css('prop', 'val'); // for example, set some css props for the matched elements
```

Answer (score 0):

James Padolsey created a wonderful filter that allows regex to be used for selection.

Take a look at this question:

[jQuery selector regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions)