# Use each function with regex in jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex

In my code I have this type of text:

```
<h1>{{text}}</h1>
<p>{{other text}}</p>
```

How to get with with jQuery, those texts ?

-

My first idea was:

```
$(regex).each(function( index ) {
  alert(index); // must return {{text}}
}
```

Comment: Are you lloking for a regexp selector? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions

Comment: jQuery doesn't accept regex as a selector, target the elements with a class or something else instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `each` incorrectly:

```
$(regex).each(function() {
  alert($(this).html()); // must return {{text}}
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TexasBrawler/fkvtaet8/1/)

Note that in the demo I used `body *` as the selector. jQuery doesn't take regex selectors, so you will need to write a proper selector.

Also note that your original code was missing `);` at the end; I have added it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me this. But how can I match the {{text}} ?

Comment: See my demo link. As long as `regex` contains a selector that matches the elements in question, the above will work.

Comment: The problem is if I have `<p>aaaaaa</p>`, it will match it whereas this text is not between `{{` and `}}`.

Comment: `body *` matches everything in a subelement of body. You can do `body,body *` if you want anything in body itself or in a subelement.

Comment: You need to filter for text matching `\{\{[^{}]+\}\}` inside the `each` function. Don't try to do this with the selector itself, or you will run into problems.