# Regex in jQuery selector doesn't accept \d?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-selectors

I am trying to only select links with "example.com/foo/12345/bar" pattern where they can be any number of digits.  But jquery doesn't seem to accept \d for digits.  Any other suggestions?

```
$('a[href*="example.com\/foo\/\d+\/bar"]').hover(function(){});
```

Comment: jQuery doesn't accept regex there, but you can use `filter`, then `regex.test(this.href)` in the callback.

Comment: The attribute selector does not accept RegEx expressions. You would either have to fetch the ID and perform the matching iteratively, or use a custom pseudo-class: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions

Comment: You might try combination of multiple attribute selector, `$('a[href*="example.com/foo"][href$="bar"]')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery doesn't accept regex there, but you can use `filter`:

```
$('a').filter(function() {
  return /example.com\/foo\/\d+\/bar/.test(this.href)
}).hover(function() {

})
```