# Javascript encode html tags but leave url links intact

Tags: javascript, html

My function for encoding HTML tags with javascript.

```
function htmlEncode(value) {
    //create a in-memory div, set it's inner text(which jQuery automatically encodes)
    //then grab the encoded contents back out.  The div never exists on the page.
    return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
}
```

how to encode everything expect html links? I don't want to encode html links, so that after encoding the user can click on a link. But I would like to encode all other html tags.

Is this possible?

Comment: This could lead to so many problems on mantaining the code, but anyway you could try with jquery not selector: http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Comment: Thx for a hin. I tried but not working as expected: return $('<div/>').text(value).not('a').html();

Comment: I suggest to try with small steps. First of all try to select only the subset of tags traversing the DOM and check out the output with console.log, then try with the manipulation/injection. I hope it helps a bit, I cannot be "operative" right now.

Comment: I was curious about your question so I decided to dig a bit more. I tried to accomplish what you are aiming to (despite the fact that I don't like the approach) and I finally decided that it is not a path that has to be followed, but still you can rethink it using this other thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions. Hope it helps.