# jQuery dynamic Right-to-Left CSS processing

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a list that might look like this:

```
<ul>
 <li>Table</li>  <!-- English -->
 <li>मेज</li>    <!-- Hindi -->
 <li>میز</li>   <!-- Urdu -->
</ul>
```

I want to use jQuery to read the characters in the list-item and if it finds any characters in the Arabic unicode range (0x0600 - 0x06FF), underline it.

Here is what I have:

```
$("li:contains(/[\u0600-\u06FF]/)").css( "text-decoration", "underline" );
```

It should match the third item but I'm obviously doing something wrong. Perhaps regular expressions are not allowed by `:contains` in jQuery selectors...

Comment: I see that people have already been thinking about this. This may be what I want to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `filter()` with a `RegExp`.
Try the following:

```
var regex = new RegExp(/[\u0600-\u06FF]/);

$("li").filter(function() {
    return regex.test($(this).text());
}).css("text-decoration", "underline");
```