# How to initialize dynamic input with css selector using query selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to initilize dynamic number with in `css` selector?

```
   Ex-pageUrl.QuerySelector(.attachment-type-table .qa-type-id-label-for-25)
```

The above line given only one Result `Photograph`.

I need to get all names with in span tag

```
( qa-type-id-label-for-26,qa-type-id-label-for-25, qa-type-id-label-for-27 etc)
```

Comment: <table id="attachmentTypeTable" class="appconfig-data-table attachment-type-table">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr id="28RemoveAType">
<tr id="27RemoveAType">
<tr id="26RemoveAType">
<td>
<span class="qa-type-id-label-for-26">Transfer cover</span>
</td>
<td>
</tr>
<tr id="25RemoveAType">
<td>
<span class="qa-type-id-label-for-25">Photograph</span>
</td>
<td>
</tr>

Comment: Are you using jQuery ? Or [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) ?

**Note:** `querySelector` will select only first matched element. If you want to access every matched element, use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: You could check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions

Comment: im using queryselector. how to initilize with queryselectorAll?Is this correct? Ex:.pageUrl.QuerySelectorAll(.attachment-type-table .qa-type-id-label-for-25).i can get only 25 object only .i need 26 and 27 too....

Comment: @reshma Use like `document.querySelectorAll('#attachmentTypeTable span')`. This will return you list of matched elements

Comment: @VigneswaranMarimuthu  i have tried with your code.im getting only one value

Comment: @reshma I tried using the markup you have commented but i don't see it is valid. Can you provide a jsfddle link ?

Answer (score 0):

Use native function  `yourSpan.attr('class')`, and then you can use `.Split(" ")`
for get individual of class.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?
   I have implemented `querySelectAll()` matching partially  to a class name.

```
<table id="attachmentTypeTable" class="appconfig-data-table attachment-type-table">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <tr id="28RemoveAType">
    <tr id="27RemoveAType">
    <tr id="26RemoveAType">
        <td><span class="qa-type-id-label-for-26">Transfer cover</span></td>
        <td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="25RemoveAType">
        <td><span class="qa-type-id-label-for-25">Photograph</span></td>
        <td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var x = document.querySelectorAll('[class^="qa-type-id-label-for-"]');
    for(var i=0;i< x.length;i++){
        document.write('result'+i+':'+x[i].innerHTML+'<br/>');
    }

</script>
```

Comment: im unable to get the values .firefox gets crashed when execute this line. var filetype= aqObject.GetPropertyValue(Page.QuerySelectorAll('[class^="qa-type-id-label-for-"]'), "contentText")