# jquery binding on several fields with regex (start with + digit)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to bind an event on all fields with an id starting with `"userLinesXXX"`
Where `XXX` will be a number (not necessary 3 digits)

this :

```
$('[id^="userLines"]').change(function() {
```

Works perfectly, but I need to add the numbers in the regex (to avoid binding on fields wit hid "userLinesAutoEdited"), but I don't know how to do.
I tried with `[id^="userLines"\d+]` and `[id^="userLines"[0-9]]` but this doesn't work...

Comment: What are `[]`  there for?

Comment: for the 0-9 you mean?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions

Comment: Thx but on that thread there's no binding with digits matching  :/

Comment: but it shows how to add a regex selector OR how to use filter function to accomplish the same result

Comment: `:regex(id, userLines[0-9]+)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use .filter with a function:

```
$('[id^="userLines"]').filter(function() {
   return !!$(this).attr('id').match(/^userLines[0-9]+$/);
}).change(function() { ... });
```