# How can I apply a regex on a jQuery selector?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I searched the net a bit but did not find a solution for my problem. This is my selector:

```
jQuery('[data-group="' + a + '"]').show()
```

The `a` is a text like `swimming` or any word. In HTML it looks like this:

```
<div data-group="swimming">...</div>
```

So the above selector would show that div if `a = swimming`. Now lets say that the data-group contains the word simming, but its not the only one, like this:

```
<div data-group="swimming,driving,flying">...</div>
```

How can I still select that div with a selector if `a = swimming`? I hope you know what I mean :).

Thanks!

Comment: Potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the value contains selector:

```
jQuery('[data-group*="' + a + '"]').show();
```

But would match even `swimming` for `a` equals `swim`.

If that matters, then filter it using e.g:

```
jQuery('[data-group]').filter(function(){
    return this.dataset.group.split(',').indexOf(a) != -1
}).show();
```

And better if you can change your HTML markup too:

```
<div data-group="swimming driving flying">...</div>
```

Then you could use:

```
jQuery('[data-group~="' + a + '"]').show();
```

Comment: Perfect, changed to ~= and changed my data-group. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
jQuery('[data-group]').filter(function(){
    return $(this).data('group').split(',').indexOf(a) > -1; //Convert to an array an check whether elements exist in array

    //Using native code
    //return this.dataset.group.split(',').indexOf(a) > -1
}).show();
```

References: [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and [HTMLElement.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)