# clean up html element coming from other source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I `console.log(data)` from my ajax callback, it returns the entire html file which includes scripts, css etc which breaks my page. How can I get only the element block which I need? I only need the data within `.container`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery selector regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions)

Comment: in ajax success try to use function(response){  alert($(response).find('.container').html());

Comment: Why don't you just return the necessary things from ajax?

Comment: @TareqMahmood that is correct.

Comment: @TareqMahmood if I can control the output it's better in json, but it's external api

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using regular expressions.

For example, if you wanted to get the content of all `.container` elements, you could try this regexp:

```
<[^>]+class="container"[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/[^>]+>
```

and then collect the captured groups.

See working example on [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/lY3zV2/1).

Answer (score 0):

I think easiest way is to use jquery load function. There is possibility to take only fragment of loaded page.

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be append in hidden tag. Then search for using $(".container")
 it will return the whole div and you can get html .
Here is script code that can help you
(use jquery library)

```
var b= $(".container");
console.log(b[0].outerHTML);
```

PLEASE CHECK THIS BELOW FIDDLE

```
http://jsfiddle.net/oyvv9nL0/
```