# Css Selector for inputs which name contains two words?

Tags: jquery, css

It is possibile to use this selector

```
$( "input[name~='man']" )
```

to identify any input in page which name contains the word 'man' but if i need to select, instead of a single word pattern i.e. 'man', a pattern containing two words like '(anything)checkbox(anything)man(anything)' so that

```
<input name="checkbox-foo-man">
<input name="checkbox-bar-man">
<input name="foo-checkbox-foo-man-foo">
```

gets selected? Possibily, impliying the right order that is 'checkbox' before 'man'

Comment: does the order of the words matter?

Comment: yes, edited the question. It matter to be specific and be sure that it select only what expected

Comment: You can achieve it using regex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions

Comment: If you don't want to use another library, you could select all the inputs with `checkbox` in the name then filter only the ones whos name attribute matches a regex.

Comment: I was hoping there was a simpler way :)

Comment: Good question. Unfortunately I don't think you can match word order with CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it without regexes by combining selectors. I don't think there's a way to ensure the order this way though.

```css
[name*="foo"][name*="bar"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div name="foo-bar"> foo-bar </div> <!-- selected -->
<div name="bar-foo"> bar-foo </div> <!-- selected -->
<div name="foo-bar-baz"> foo-bar-baz </div> <!-- selected -->
<div name="foo-baz"> foo-baz </div>
<div name="bar-baz"> bar-baz </div>
```

Comment: Maybe this helps you: `input[name*='man']:not([name^='man'])`. It selects all inputs that **contain** the word `man` but doesn't **start with** `man`

Comment: Works like a charm! It was good to have the order, but I can deal with that. In my answer case, it was input[name*="checkbox"][name*="man"]. Thank you