# jQuery Get all elements where class contains a number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get all elements that class contains a number, how can I do that?
I haven't tried anything because I don't really know how to think about it.

Comment: @PeterB I know about that, although I can't use it for containing number.

Comment: @BerkayGunduz try `.match(/[0-9]+/)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be related to this question: [jQuery selector regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions)

Using the regex functionality from this [page](https://j11y.io/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/), you should be able to do something like this:

```
$(':regex(class,.*[0-9].*)');
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by iterating over all desired elements, keeping only those where the `className` attribute matches a given regex.

```js
var divs = $('div');
var regex = /\d/;
var result = divs.filter(index => regex.test(divs[index].className));

result.each(index => console.log(result[index]));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="x1" class="a"></div>
<div id="x2" class="a1"></div>
<div id="x3" class="2a"></div>
<div id="x4" class="3"></div>
<div id="x5" class="bc"></div>
<div id="x6" class="x4y5z"></div>
```