# How to use regex in jquery attributes?

Tags: jquery, regex

I've tried to use regex to find all elements that have indexed id "modal[index]"
like this

```
$("input[id=modal[\[0-9\+]]").attr("disabled", "false");
```

this error raised

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
>   input[id=modal[[0-9+]]

and tried using for loop but the same error occured

```
for(var j=1;j<11;j++)
    $("input[id=modal["+j+"]]").attr("disabled", "false");
```

how to find these elements ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [filter function](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#expr) of JQuery, below example should work for you. [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/193787/4395050)

```js
$('input')
  .filter(function() {
      return this.id.match('\[0-9\+]');
  }).attr("disabled", "false");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="modal[8]" value="this textbox will disabled"/>
<input type="text" id="modal[a]" value="this will not"/>
```

and if you want to achieve this with for loop consider below example.

i have made few changes to your for loop

> for(var `j=0`;j<`$("input[type='text']").length`;j++)
>
> $("input[id=`'modal["+j+"]'`]")

```js
for(var j=0;j<$("input[type='text']").length;j++)
    $("input[id='modal["+j+"]']").attr("disabled", "false");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="modal[0]" value="this textbox will disabled"/>
<input type="text" id="modal[1]" value="this will not"/>
```

Comment: this solution works for all inputs that have indexed id .. for example if i have another input of id "mod[1]" this input will be disabled too .

Comment: your question `How to use regex in jquery attributes?` clearly mention that you were trying to find elements with regex so i provided you solution for that

Answer (score 0):

var regix = new RegExp([0-9+]);
futher read about its functions like .test etc

Answer (score 0):

if your id looks something like **modal[1]**, **modal [2]**, then:

```
for(var j=1;j<11;j++) {
  $("input#modal["+j+"]").attr("disabled", "false");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me is to remove the disabled attribute from the input attributes using CSS selectors without using regex like so

```
$('input[id^=modal]').removeAttr("disabled");
```

thank you all for your answers