# jQuery select within names that are nested arrays

Tags: jquery, css

Suppose I have a form with input element naming scheme that is a multidimensional array. Such as:

```
<form>
    <input type="number" name="foo[123][456][789]" />
</form>
```

Is it possible to use jQuery (CSS selectors) to select all inputs where the name starts with foo, and has a specific value in the second array selector?

For example, the following is a possible valid selection (second array selector is always 456):

```
<input type="number" name="foo[123][456][1]" />
<input type="number" name="foo[422][456][2]" />
<input type="number" name="foo[443][456][3]" />
<input type="number" name="foo[211][456][4]" />
```

Comment: Not a single selector but I am pretty sure you can use a function and select the ones you need. Getting the foo start is really easy, you just have to sort out the stuff after it

Comment: You can use `input[name^='foo[']` to match names that start with `foo[`. Use `.filter()` with a function of your own that looks for `456`.

Comment: There are also third-party add-ons that implement regular expression attribute selection. You could use that.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions

Comment: Looks like I am wrong about the single selector, `input[name^="foo["][name*="][456]["] ` https://jsfiddle.net/cph8defg/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). `^=` is for selecting on attribute values that begin with the specified string. `*=` is for selecting on attribute values that contain the specified string. Quoting included so the brackets don't confuse the selector.

```
$('input[name^="foo["][name*="][456]["]')
```

In English: Select `input` elements that have an attribute called `name` whose value begins with `foo[` and have an attribute called `name` whose value contains `][456][`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work but this does `input[name^="foo["][name*="][456]["] ` ~ version only works for white space separated

Comment: @Huangism Corrected