# How to craft a selector in jQuery to account for ids with sequential numbering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

How to, in one selector, account for a selector that has a format like `attr1, attr2, attr3` etc until `attr9` so that I can create a click method in jQuery?  I'm unable to come up with anything myself I'm sure and I'm tired here at work and can't think straight!!

Any ideas? Thanks! Here's what I have

```
$( () => {
    $('#attr' + ).click( () => {
        $(this).next('div').slideToggle();

        $(this).parent().siblings().children().next().slideUp();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I think a regex would be the way to go. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions

Comment: You need `$('[id^=attr]')` (although this will match any id that starts with `attr`. why are you working with sequential IDs in the first place? Can't you use something like `#parent > div` instead?)

Comment: Use a class instead.  Super easy.