# Multiple buttons selection by names in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I tried using the following code:

```
$('button[name^="X,Y,Z"]').on("click",function(){
    // code here
});
```

to replace this code but it didn't work. Anybody has a work around to make it shorter :) **without using class or ids**

```
$('button[name^="X"],button[name^="Y"],button[name^="Z"]').on("click",function(){
    // code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a more compact format for that selector, but you could create a function that generates a selector string from a comma separated string.

```js
const btnNameBegins = function(values) {
  return values.split(',').map(value => 'button[name^="' + value + '"]').join(',')
}

$(btnNameBegins('X,Y,Z')).on("click", function() {
  console.log(this.name);
}).addClass('hilite');

// output the selector string for demonstration
console.log(btnNameBegins('X,Y,Z'));
```

```css
.hilite {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button name="Wstuff">W</button>
<button name="Xstuff">X</button>
<button name="Ystuff">Y</button>
<button name="Zstuff">Z</button>
<button name="4stuff">4</button>
```

Another idea is to remove the element type from the function and filter a selection of `<button>` elements. That way, you could use the function more generally to filter any other selector.

```js
const nameBegins = function(values) {
  return values.split(',').map(value => '[name^="' + value + '"]').join(',')
}

$('button').filter(nameBegins('X,Y,Z')).on("click", function() {
  console.log('Button: ' + this.innerHTML);
}).addClass('hilite');

$('.active').filter(nameBegins('B,C,D')).on("click", function() {
  console.log('Checkbox: ' + this.value);
}).addClass('hilite');

// output the selector string for demonstration
console.log(nameBegins('X,Y,Z'));
```

```css
.hilite {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button name="Wstuff">W</button>
<button name="Xstuff">X</button>
<button name="Ystuff">Y</button>
<button name="Zstuff">Z</button>
<button name="4stuff">4</button>

<input type="checkbox" name="Astuff" value="A">
<input type="checkbox" name="Bstuff" value="B" class="active">
<input type="checkbox" name="Cstuff" value="C">
<input type="checkbox" name="Dstuff" value="D">
<input type="checkbox" name="Estuff" value="E" class="active">
```

Also see [Regex in Jquery Selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions).