# How can I target all anchor tags that have an fragment url reference?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Say in my html I have the following anchor tags:

```html
<a href="#fragment1">
  link 1
</a>
<a href="http://someExternalResource.com">
  link 2
</a>
<a href="#fragment2">
  link 3
</a>
```

What kind of selector string would I pass into `document.querySelectorAll` to select links 1 and  3 based on the idea that they are internal anchor fragment links. Alternatively, any other solution to target those would be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

The following will select all elements with a href attribute that starts with a #. `document.querySelectorAll('[href^="#"]')`

I hope that helps.

Comment: Also, could you perhaps point to documentation for the `^` part. Is that an html thing or a js thing? I'm curious if i can do this with any attribute

Comment: The ^ arrow is a regular expression for 'the begging of the line'.querySlector support a subset of regular expressions. 

There's a regex cheat sheet here: https://medium.com/factory-mind/regex-tutorial-a-simple-cheatsheet-by-examples-649dc1c3f285.

Comment: @StephenBaker CSS selectors and Regex are different unrelated things. What you used is an attribute selector, which is one of many operators from a CSS selector.

Comment: @AndrewKim yes, you can use attribute selectors for any attributes. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp) you can find other helpful attribute selectors.

Comment: @PedroLima You are correct but he asked specifically about the ^. All the attribute selectors have origins in regex. Understanding the origins of these selectors is just as important.

Comment: @StephenBaker Not all of them. No. I can only think of ^ and $ as common symbols between them (you may correct me if I am wrong). They decided to use the same symbol as it's easier to memorize, but the usage is different, the syntax is different, regex have many symbols css don't, css have many symbols regex don't... At the end of the day, they are unrelated things. The thing that bugged me the most is that you even provided a link to a regex tutorial.

Comment: how to select all links that not start with # in JavaScript

Comment: @LbAbid there are lots of ways to do this but based on the above, this would do the opposite and select all without a # document.querySelectorAll("a:not([href^='#'])"

Comment: Done, i got the script

Answer (score 0):

Other alternatives would be to use jQuery with regex for the specific anchor href.
see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions) for more information.

```
$('a:regex(href, ^#fragment.*)');
```