# How to ignore a part of search string in cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

Given the following:

`cy.get('div[class="specialId-1111-button"]')`

and the number `1111` can change after each `npm install`, how can I replace that number to something like `specialId-*-button` when searching for a selector, so it could grab selector with any number in it. I understand that's not the right syntax, but looking for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `*`. It basically says that the text we are searching for should be present in the string, which in your case is **specialId**. So, you can write something like:

```
cy.get('div[class*="specialId"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [jQuery contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
cy.get('div[class*="specialId-"]')
```

or the [jQuery starts-with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
cy.get('div[class^="specialId-"]')
```

or the [jQuery ends-with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)

```
cy.get('div[class$="-button"]')
```

or a combination

```
cy.get('div[class^="specialId-"][class$="-button"]')
```

for example if you need to exclude ***specialId-1111-checkbox***

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match the text on both sides of the number, you're best off using a [regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions).

Answer (score 0):

Playing around with the regex idea, purely to see how practical it is.

You can enhance jQuery with custom functions like this one [Regex Selector for jQuery](https://j11y.io/snippets/regex-selector-for-jquery).

To use it in Cypress, you can add it like this (updated from the original)

**cypress/support/index.js**

```js
const jQuery = Cypress.$;
jQuery.expr[':'].regex = function(elem, index, match) {

  const matchParams = match[3].split(',');
  const validLabels = /^(data|css):/;
  const attr = {
    method: matchParams[0].match(validLabels) ? matchParams[0].split(':')[0] : 'attr',
    property: matchParams.shift().replace(validLabels,'')
  }
  const regexFlags = 'ig';
  const regex = new RegExp(matchParams.join('').replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,''), regexFlags);

  return regex.test(jQuery(elem)[attr.method](attr.property));
}
```

**test**

```js
cy.get("div:regex(class, specialId-.+-button)")
```

**So:**

- **overkill for this scenario** but might have uses when requirements are more complicated
- does not follow the convention that Cypress uses for regex, i.e `/` delimiters given in source
- does not seem to allow the regex escape char `\`, so for example could not use the more exact expression /specialId-\d+-button/

---

Looking at the second answer in [jQuery selector regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/193787/14903560), the jQuery `filter()` method can be used to do some interesting stuff.

```js
cy.get('div')
  .invoke('filter', function() {
    // use complex jQuery expressions here
    return this.classList[0].match(/specialId-\d+-button/);  
  })
  .should('have.length', 1);
```

**Note**

- also **overkill for this question**
- can use some quite complex javascript in the filter function
- doesn't require a jQuery patch function