# How to disable an input in HTML/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

How to disable an input and enable through button click if the ID is something like this `id="qty_<?php echo $x; ?>"` not a normal `id="qty"`

```
<input type="number" name="qty[]" min="0" id="qty_<?php echo $x; ?>" class="form-control" required onclick="getTotal(<?php echo $x; ?>)" onkeyup="getTotal(<?php echo $x; ?>)" value="<?php echo $val['qty'] ?>" autocomplete="off">
```

javascript - how to use this kind of id? `id="qty_<?php echo $x; ?>`

```
function enablebutton(){    
  $('*#my_field').prop( "disabled", false );

}
```

the normal id like `id="qty"` is working but i need the solution on how to use this kind of id `id="qty_<?php echo $x; ?>"` when enable/disable an input

Comment: There is only one input which id start  with `qty_` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190253/jquery-selector-regular-expressions `$('input[id^=qty_]')`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have the following button:

```
<input type=button value="Disable" onclick='javascript:disablebutton(<?php echo $x; ?>)'>
```

Then the JS function to disable the element with `id ="qty_<?php echo $x; ?>` will be

```
function disablebutton(var1){    
  $('#qty_' + var1).prop( "disabled", true );

}
```

Note: for enablebutton, it will be

```
function enablebutton(var1){    
  $('#qty_' + var1).prop( "disabled", false );
}
```

So, put them all together, will be like

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-3zlB5s2uwoUzrXK3BT7AX3FyvojsraNFxCc2vC/7pNI="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<?php $x=1; ?>

<input id="qty_<?php echo $x; ?>" value=10>
<input type=button value="Disable" onclick='javascript:disablebutton(<?php echo $x; ?>)'>
<input type=button value="Enable" onclick='javascript:enablebutton(<?php echo $x; ?>)'>

<script>
function disablebutton(var1){    
  $('#qty_' + var1).prop( "disabled", true );
}

function enablebutton(var1){    
  $('#qty_' + var1).prop( "disabled", false );
}
</script>
```

You may click this sandbox to see the effect:

http://www.createchhk.com/SOanswers/testSO26Nov2022.php

Of course in practice, you may have multiple input boxes with multiple buttons, so changing the `$x` value dynamically (e.g use the database key) will be the usual way to do it.